# Center anchor with image in div

Tags: image, css, alignment, anchor

I have an image that's in an anchor element.

I want the anchor an the image to be centered both vertically and horizontally in the parent div.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shimmy/REpYn/)'s an example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="anchor">
        <img src="http://bit.ly/1mFH8AW"></img>
    </a>
</div>
.wrapper {
    background: black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
.anchor {
}
.anchor > img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to your wrapper and then change the image's CSS to:

```
.anchor > img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/REpYn/2/)**

Comment: Why margin auto and not margin 0 auto

Comment: Because `0 auto` would only center it horizontally and the OP asked for both vertically and horizontally. Auto takes care of all four simultaneously.