# Aligning an image inside a container (width auto and height auto)

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to center the image, even when the width and height of the image is set to auto? This is the code I have:

```
.IMGContainer {
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
height: 50%;
max-height: 50%;
top: 24%;
position: absolute; 
display: block;
}
.IMGContainer img {
position: absolute;
height: auto;
width: auto;
max-height: 80%;
max-width: 80%;
}
```

The images are a bit landscape therefor I am forced to use the auto setting to the height and width; what can I use to center the image even though the width and height is undetermined for?

Comment: Add the html and create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hj49B/)

```
 .IMGContainer img{
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        position:absolute;
        margin:auto;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
       }
```

Note: the css block

```
position:absolute;
            margin:auto;
            top:0;
            right:0;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
```

will center the image in the container..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
   .IMGContainer img{
    width: auto;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
     }
```

Change the value of x to suitable value.

Reference - [Center anchor with image in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23282890/center-anchor-with-image-in-div)